# How to best include microdata with SVG for dynamic maps?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, svg, microdata

Task: To make dynamic and styled metro maps with SVG like e.g. this map of Beijing http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Beijing-Subway-Plan_en.svg

Goal: To make a collection of metro (or similar) maps in the public domain using a standard format, with a small library of scripts and stylesheets, easy for future developers to adapt to own use.

Challenge: To make similar maps enhanceable, animatable, and stylable based on HTML-style microdata. These data include, but will not be limited to time and geodata. E.g. station opening date, longitude and latitude of each station, travel time between stations and so on. These microdata will be used for animation, styling, and future use.

An example animation would be this, using SVG animation: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/History_of_Beijing_Subway_en.gif

What would be the most developer-friendly way of attaching these microdata?

(More background to project, for those interested: http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=1609787 )

Comment: Regarding HTML5 microdata, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=909633.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot one implicit requirement, the dynamic maps will have to work with reasonably modern browsers, those that support SVG obviously. HTML microdata wouldn't work for that reason, and out for both HTML and SVG. 

Microdata was a WHATWG response to microformats, and microformats might be a possible solution to this problem. Here is the page on geodata: http://microformats.org/wiki/location-formats Typically HTML microformats use 'div', 'span', and 'class' to encode the semantic data, SVG has similar elements like 'g' to abuse.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the microdata attributes are only defined for HTML elements, which means they won't be processed in SVG. I would recommend to look at RDFa which is designed to work in many formats such as HTML, XML and SVG:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-primer/

Comment: The challenge is that we need not just to encode semantic data, saying e.g. that this metro station is located at this longitude and latitude, or that it was opened at this date. This data will be used for dynamic purposes, e.g. the geolocation to "stretch" to their actual location or opening date to animate the chronological development of a network. Some of these functions we will make, others the map users may make on their own. 

In other words to go the RDFa path there has to be an efficient and easy to use Javascript API. I don't know if there is one, but can ask the RDFa community.

Comment: I added this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001054/javascript-api-for-animating-svg-using-rdfa-metadata

Answer (score 0):

The most correct and standard approach would be to use the SVG `<metadata>` tag.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/metadata.html

The metadata should be in RDF format.  All you would need to do is use an appropriate RDF Schema that already exists, or create your own schema suitable for your use.

Comment: That would allow us to attach semantic information to SVG elements (e.g. that this station/'circle' was opened at this date), but doesn't by itself solve the bigger question: How to extract this information again (e.g. for given station what is its opening date) and apply it (e.g. to do the time animation in the opening question).

I asked an additional question, hopefully it will give some answers to this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001054/javascript-api-for-animating-svg-using-rdfa-metadata

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to this problem, inspired by HTML microformats (that embed the information to extra HTML elements, usually 'div' and 'span'). Something similar could be achieved in SVG by using primarily the 'g' element.

Relatively to RDFa it will have some disadvantages. Outside the map-making community, people wouldn't tell that a particular piece of information would be an opening date, for instance. It would mean some additional SVG markup to embed this information. On the other hand it is a more straightforward and readable approach. But how would it handle the challenge and achieve the goal?

Today's map markup ([after being cleaned up](http://files.myopera.com/jax/svg/Beijing-Subway-Plan-2015.svg)) might look something like this for a station (Beijing Railway Station in this case):

```
<circle id="circle452" cx="1512.523" cy="1300.289" r="5.625" class="station"/>
<text dx="1522.5999" dy="1321.2517" xml:lang="en" class="station-name">Beijing Railway Station</text>
<text dx="1522.9651" dy="1306.156" xml:lang="zh" class="station-name">北京站</text>
```

The three station components above are not actually connected in any way, except by visual proximity. A first stab of a microformatted metro station representation could be something like this:

```
<g class="station">
    <metadata>
         <desc class="opening-date">1971-11-7</desc>
         <desc class="coordinates">116.41735553741455,39.90104520501837,0.0</desc>
   </metadata>
    <circle id="circle452" cx="1512.523" cy="1300.289" r="5.625" class="icon"/>
    <text dx="1522.5999" dy="1321.2517" xml:lang="en" class="name">Beijing Railway Station</text>
    <text dx="1522.9651" dy="1306.156" xml:lang="zh" class="name">北京站</text>
</g>
```

This has some advantages relative to the first approach as the related elements (the station symbol, the name in English and simplified Chinese) are now structurally related, together with the metadata.

For the first attempt I used the 'metadata' element together with the 'desc' element. This may or may not be a good choice. The 'metadata' should be fine, but the 'desc' element is intended for a human audience, not a Javascript. Finding elements that are side-effect-free is imperative, both with SVG renderers and other SVG processors (e.g. an SVG screen reader). I cannot yet tell if 'desc' fills the bill.

Furthermore, will this handle the challenge and fulfil the goal? In other words would it be easy to extract and apply these data for animations?

(Structurally I would assume an RDFa solution would look something similar, only with RDF where the 'desc' elements are now.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend one of two methods.

Both involve having a legend or similar reference to the SVG map in HTML5. Then use the Microdata for the legend. Make sure to reference the SVG within the page by:

- Using the id attribute in the SVG so that the HTML Microdata can have a link using the itemprop attribute to the URL fragment, `#svgobject1`
- Less likely to be used, but interestingly allowed possible is to use the itemref attribute in HTML legend. I would avoid this as it is messy.

Another approach to take in addition to the above is to use the itemid attribute. I would recommend this for any Microdata item if possible. Decide if the SVG map legend is the original authentic collection of items. If so, then the include id attributes in each of the HTML tags with itemscope and then add itemid with the URL with fragment being itself (example:

```
<div id="itemid" itemscope="" itemid="http://maps.cn/beijing.html#itemid">
```

)

Or create or reference another web page(s) of yours or someone else's, preferably with the Microdata item in it and a decent itemtype reference.